# Set value to Array inside FormControl

Tags: html, arrays, angular, typescript, form-control

I have an FormControl that's declared as an Array of a specific type and I need to populate it with another array of the same type but, I can't figure out how to do so.
Here's my code:

```
profileData = new FormGroup({
  // Some Form Controls here...
  selectedInterests: new FormControl([], Validators.required)
});

constructor(
  public cookieService: CookieService,
  public router: Router,
  private profileService: ProfileService,
  private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
  private translateService: TranslateService
) {
  this.loadUserProfile();
}

private loadUserProfile() {
  this.profileService.loadProfile(this.cookieService.get('UserId')).then(loadedProfile => {
    this.profile = loadedProfile;
    // Data loads here...
    this.profileData.controls['selectedInterests'].setValue(loadedProfile.interests);
    // This line gives the error:
    //   Argument of type 'Interest[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 
    //   'never[]'.
    //   Type 'Interest' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    this.cookieService.get('UserId');
  });
}
```

I selected only the parts that are important for the question, I can add more info if needed.

HTML:

```
          <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>{{ 'INTEREST.INTEREST' | translate }}</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="selectedInterests" multiple>
              <mat-option *ngFor="let interest of interests" [value]="interest">
                <!-- {{ interest | translate }} -->
                {{ interest.name }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <mat-error *ngIf="profileData.controls.selectedInterest.hasError('required')">
              {{ 'PROFILE.VALID.INTEREST' | translate }}
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

PS: I'm using Angular 16

Comment: Why not use a FormArray instead?

Comment: The Array is bind to a  multiple selection Material Select component! I don't need to each `Interest` object instance to be a control, they just need to be shown to then be selected or unselected.

Comment: `selectedInterests: new FormControl<Interest[]>([], Validators.required)`, see the docs about [typed Forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms)

Comment: @Eliseo it worked! Thank you so much! You need to answer the question so I can accept it tho

Comment: @AlfredoMarin, just do it, but don't worry, I'm happy to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comment in an answer

```
selectedInterests: new FormControl<Interest[]>([], Validators.required)
```

We can check the docs about [typed Forms](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms)

Another way is use some "bizarro" like

```
selectedInterests: new FormControl<any>([], Validators.required)
```

but we loose the capacity of typescript check ours errors